# Alias attr_reader in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to alias an `attr_reader` method in Ruby? I have a class with a `favourites` property that I want to alias to `favorites` for American users. What's the idiomatic Ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

attr_reader simply generates appropriate instance methods. This:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar
end
```

is identical to:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end
end
```

therefore, alias_method works as you'd expect it to:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :favourites
  alias_method :favorites, :favourites

  # and if you also need to provide writers
  attr_writer :favourites
  alias_method :favorites=, :favourites=
end
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can just use the alias method. A very scrappy example:

```
class X
  attr_accessor :favourites
  alias :favorites :favourites
end
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Is there any reason to prefer `alias` to `alias_method`?

Comment: `alias` is a keyword and therefore a little more low-level than `alias_method`. `alias` will resolve methods statically, while `alias_method` does depend on the current `self`. See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/135598#604485 (but for your use case, it makes no difference)

Comment: For this example is pretty much the same thing. alias and alias_method within a class defenition do the same thing given that the methods you are trying to alias are instance methods. If you use alias outside a class definition, lets say inside a instance_eval, your 'aliasing' a method of self, thus creating a singleton method for that object. If self happens to be a class then you're 'aliasing' a instance method to a singleton method of the class, which as you might have guess is in fact a class method.

Comment: The `alias` keyword can be confusing or surprising. I would recommend to use `alias_method` http://stackoverflow.com/q/4763121/159721