# Rails How to add observer to only one custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, observer-pattern

I would like to create an observer which will observe only one custom method.

I got Baner model. For each call for `image` method I would like to increase `pageview` field.

```
class Baner < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :image

def pageview_inc
  pageview += 1
  save
end

alias old_image image

def image
  old_image
end
end
```

Is it possibly to set observer for only one custom method?
That after `image` method call `pageview_inc` method will be executed.

**EDIT**

If i change that method for

```
  def image                                                            
    old_image
    self.pageview   += 1
    self.save!
  end
```

And I get `stack level too deep.`

The same effect for

```
  def image    
    self.pageview   += 1
    self.save!                                                        
    old_image
  end
```

Comment: why don't you call the method at the end of `image`?

Comment: It tried that. But I get a recursion and I get stack level to deep.

Comment: Are you using an observer? If so, where is the observer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Baner < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image

  alias_method :old_image, :image

  def image
    increment!(:pageview)
    old_image
  end
end
```

Two things here:

1) see this question: [Should I use alias or alias_method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763121/ruby-should-i-use-alias-or-alias-method)

2) `increment!` will update the counter without saving the entire model, avoiding possible calls to `image` in the process of saving it (thus causing a recursion loop).

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish your goal:

```
def image
  old_image
  write_attribute("pageview", pageview + 1)
end
```