# Alias instance variable in subclass

Tags: ruby, alias, instance-variables

I'd like to alias an instance variable, so the alias can be used in the subclass (or in the class itself, for that matter).
Here is a simplified demonstration of what I'd like to achieve

```
class A

    attr_reader :bar
    alias :foo :bar

    def initialize
        @bar = 'hello'
    end

end

class B < A

    def try_alias
        puts @foo
    end

end

B.new.try_alias #=> "hello"
```

But it doesn't work, @foo is nil. Is there a way to achieve it somehow? Or do I have to change/set @foo whenever I change @bar to mimic this behaviour?

EDIT: It seems the way I am trying to do the alias would work if called

```
foo
```

instead of

```
@foo
```

in the try_alias method, which is not surprising. Trying to use

```
alias :@foo :bar
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: `alias :foo :bar` creates an alias for the method `bar`, not for the instance variable `@bar`. Instance variables cannot be aliased.

Comment: Please explain a use case where you would need to store 2 identical instance variables because as I understand your question right now `@foo` should be a direct reference to `@bar` e.g. `@foo.equal?(@bar) #=> true`. Currently in your case changing `puts @foo` (instance variable) to `puts foo` (method call) will result in the desired behavior although I would recommend `alias_method` for inheritance over `alias`

Comment: @engineersmnky it is a matter of backward compatibility. I have a class with instance variable bar which has to be renamed to foo, so everyone who uses this class as a superclass wouldn't have to rename all of its usages.

Comment: This does not seem logical to me since you cannot alias an instance variable and this change would break compatibility this should be a major release and the CHANGE LOG should notate the change explicitly so that others can upgrade their code accordingly

Comment: Additionally this "do I have to change/set @foo whenever I change @bar to mimic this behaviour?" is also not possible as it would require the ability to overwrite assignment `=` which you cannot do

Comment: @engineersmnky what I meant by that is: having two instance variables with the same value assigned to them (no aliasing, only mimicking it).

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader :bar` creates a "getter" method for `@bar`, saving you the trouble of doing it yourself:

```
def bar
  @bar
end
```

(See [Module#attr_reader](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader)). To create an alias for the method `bar` you write

```
alias :foo :bar
```

which is effectively the same as creating a second getter for `@bar` named `foo`:

```
def foo
  @bar
end
```

Therefore `puts foo` reduces to `puts @bar`.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But it doesn't solve what I wanted to do (which apparently isn't possible at all, according to other answers). I wanted to explicitly use @foo (aliased) and not just foo.

Answer (score 0):

You should **explicitly use `@foo`** in the original, aliased `setter`; which will add just one line to your code.

- Notice that, as you made `A` superclass, generally you would
  want to validate before setting some variables, such as `@bar`. This the reason why the validation function was added to the code below (just to reflect this idea).

Also, as `attr` s declarations will be translated to `methods`, methods are the ones that master the final behaviour and, therefore, in general, it is better to use `alias_method` over *alias* (please, see [this widely accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763178/4352306)).

I would dare say this is the simplest way to go:

```
module Aside
  class A
    attr_reader :bar
    # as mentioned, preferable to use alias_method
    alias_method :foo, :bar
    alias_method :foo=, :bar=

    def initialize
      # use setter method to keep @bar and @foo in sync
      self.bar = 'hello'
    end
    def bar=(value)
      @bar = nil
      @bar = value if some_validation?(value)
      @foo = @bar
    end

    private
    def some_validation?(value)
      value.is_a?(String)
    end
  end

  class B < A
    def try_alias
      puts @foo
    end
  end
end

Aside::B.new.try_alias #=> "hello"
```

Please, observe that the `initialize` of the `class A`, uses the `setter method`, rather than the direct assignment (as in your example), to initialize `@bar`.

This is because after aliasing this way, to keep in sync `@bar` and `@foo`, you should avoid direct variable assignment everywhere other than the `bar setter` itself (aside note: that is good practice anyway, because you centralize all the validation of `@foo` to one single point).

In other words, when you want to use this approach:

- do **not use** `direct assignment` **:** `@bar = value` or `@foo = value`, and
- **use** `setter methods` instead **:** `self.bar = value` or `self.foo = value` (as shown in the `class A` initializer).