# In Ruby, why is it not enough to alias `method_missing` to catch call to undefined methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, alias

That seems all the more unexpected when defining a dummy method passing all arguments do the job. That is the following works:

```
  def method_missing(ago, *lokatoj, &bloko)
    mistrafe(ago, *lokatoj, &bloko)
  end

  def mistrafe(ago, *lokatoj, &bloko)
    # faru ion
  end
```

While the following doen't

```
alias mistrafe method_missing
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Why don't you move the implementation into `method_missing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want `method_missing` (that is called by Ruby internally) to be an alias for `mistrafe` not vice versa. You have an implementation in `mistrafe` and you want reassign `method_missing` to be calling it.

That said, the following will work:

```
alias method_missing mistrafe
```

See the [alias documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias).

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm astonished with my own confusion as with other methods aliases, I didn't made this error of inverting parameters. Now to be complete, for some reason in this case it seems required to put the alias *after* the method definition, when I can successfully alias other methods before there definition. Any idea why is that so?

Comment: Use [`Module#alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) to put it wherever. `alias` requires the method to exist due to it’s syntax.

Comment: But before you use `alias_method` over `alias`, first have a look at the differences and decide for yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310250/3982562

Comment: Understandably, `alias` can't be aliased as it's a language keyword, and no keyword can be aliased. But shouldn't it possible to alias `alias_method`? I tried to make `alias alivoke alias_method` and ended with `undefined method `alias_method' for module `Ĝue' (NameError)`

Comment: class Module
    alias_method :alivoke, :alias_method
  ;end

Comment: Thus said, @mudasobwa and @johan-wentholt even with `alias_method` it only works if it's placed after the `mistrafe` method.