# Ruby alias alias_method confusion

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code here:

```
class MyFile
  attr_accessor :byte_content

  alias_method :read,  :byte_content
  alias_method :write, :byte_content=
end
```

On the class `MyFile` there is an `alias_method`, but I do not understand how this method is working. Does it change the way the getter and setter for `:byte_content` are called?

Also, what is the difference between this method and just using `alias`? When should I one over the other?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could explain *precisely* what is unclear to you about the documentation of `Module#alias_method`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't have the same problems you have. Also, it saves time and effort for people answering your question, so that they don't repeat things you already know, or repeat explanations that you don't understand. And lastly, it would help if you can check that your [mcve] really *is* minimal. Are you absolutely certain that your problem cannot possibly be replicated in less than 25 lines?

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will certainly keep this in mind in the future. I got confused about when to use one or the other regarding lexical scope, which I did not see in the documentation (there is only one example and it is not clear at all).
I found this blog post about the topic and found it to be really helpful : https://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html

My intention is to help other beginners (like myself) that face the same doubt in the future.

Comment: Google "Ruby alais vs. alais method" and you will get plenty of hits that will tell you all you need to know about that, and much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
attr_accessor :byte_content
```

Essentially does:

```
def byte_content
  @byte_content
end 

def byte_content=(value)
  @byte_content = value
end
```

Then

```
alias_method :read, :byte_content
alias_method :write, :byte_content=
```

will create copies of the `byte_content` and `byte_content=` methods with `read` and `write` as the new names . If you modify the `byte_content` or `byte_content=` methods after the aliasing, the `read` and `write` will remain unchanged.

So, the intention of the `alias_method` in the example appears to be to give the user a more "`File`-like" interface. Without the method aliases, you would use:

```
file = MyFile.new
file.byte_content = "abcd"
puts file.byte_content
```

With the aliases, the user can use:

```
file = MyFile.new
file.write("abcd")
file.read
```

Which is quite similar to the methods of the standard library `File` class,

```
file = File.open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'w')
file.write('hello')
file.rewind
puts file.read
```

And this makes it possible to use instances of `MyFile` in place of real `File` instances in some very simple use-cases, also known as [Duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

#### `alias` vs `alias_method`

The differences of `alias` and `alias_method` are described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4763121/681520), most imporantly:

- you can override `alias_method` but not `alias`
- `alias_method` is used with symbols as the method names, making it useful for dynamically created methods

Comment: The reason that alias_method can be overwritten is because it creates a copy of the method. In your example of `alias_method :read, :byte_content` the content of the read method should be `@byte_content`.

Comment: @vise Updated the answer to mention the copying.

Comment: That was extremely helpful. Thank you!